How to display emails associated with a specific account when a contact is linked to multiple accounts in Salesforce?

I have set up a contact with multiple accounts as required for our business process. Additionally, I am using Einstein Activity Capture to sync emails associated with accounts and contacts. However, I noticed that when a contact is related to two accounts, all their emails are synced to both accounts.
Is there a way to configure Einstein Activity Capture or Salesforce so that emails are only displayed in the account they are specifically associated with, even if the contact is linked to multiple accounts?


Did you manage to resolve this issue or find a work around? We are looking at the same issue at the moment and cannot find a solution.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to resolve this issue yet.
